# Django-admin isn't detected - windows

Tags: python, django, django-admin

No matter what I try, I CANNOT use django admin to start a python project. Django is installed, in site-packages. I can call it from the python shell. Python is configured and is in my PATH. I've tried with venv and without. I'm out of solutions. Any ideas?

(I'm using the python 3.7 installation from the windows store)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this approach,

first open that project folder or directory by terminal (do not launch virtual enviroment at here), then apply following commands;

```
pipenv shell

pipenv install django==3.0

python manage.py runserver
```

Note: if pipenv is not installed than run this command first;
`pip install pipenv` (not in virtual environment)
then follow the above commands.

Comment: Ill look into it. Thanks

Comment: Even after installation i get this: pipenv : The term 'pipenv' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program.
Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1

Comment: you need to provide screenshots of the error and also files of your project to help you better.